# angular 4, globally import external javascript

Tags: angular, webpack

I know this question has been asked before, but after searching and trying tons of things I have to ask.

I'm using the [Angular Starter](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter) package and try to import an [external javascript library](https://github.com/blueimp/JavaScript-Load-Image)

I have no problem importing it directly into my component like so

```
import * as loadImage from 'blueimp-load-image/js/index.js';
```

But as far as I know I should import external scripts (with async operations) before zone.js because it may otherwise cause problems with change detection.
In fact that is exactly the problem I'm experiencing with Safari in iOS. Currently I have to manually call change detection.

In angular starter package `zone.js` is required in a file called `polyfills.ts` which is added as a chunk/js file by webpack.

```
import 'blueimp-javascript-to-blob-for-angular';
//how to import so it's useable in any component?
import 'blueimp-load-image/js/index';
import 'core-js/es6';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

require('zone.js/dist/zone');

if ('production' !== ENV) {
    Error['stackTraceLimit'] = Infinity;
    require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');
}
```

**How and where can I import my external javascript file (content below) before zone.js so I can still use it in my component?**

So far my problem has been that I can't acccess the external libraries functions because they were always `undefined`. But they have been added to the generated javascript files.

the whole process of importing external javascript into an angular 4 project seems very complicated to me.

Content of Javascript file:

```
module.exports = require('./load-image')

require('./load-image-scale')
require('./load-image-meta')
require('./load-image-fetch')
require('./load-image-exif')
require('./load-image-exif-map')
require('./load-image-orientation')
```

Comment: did you have a chance to try [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45793458/2545680)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `AddAssetHtmlPlugin` as shown [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.dev.js#L180)

```
  /**
   * Plugin: AddAssetHtmlPlugin
   * Description: Adds the given JS or CSS file to the files
   * Webpack knows about, and put it into the list of assets
   * html-webpack-plugin injects into the generated html.
   *
   * See: https://github.com/SimenB/add-asset-html-webpack-plugin
   */
  // new AddAssetHtmlPlugin([
  //   { filepath: helpers.root(`dll/${DllBundlesPlugin.resolveFile('polyfills')}`) },
  //   { filepath: helpers.root(`dll/${DllBundlesPlugin.resolveFile('vendor')}`) }
  // ]),
```

you need to create another `entry` point [here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/blob/master/config/webpack.common.js#L63) that will require external js file and load using the `AddAssetHtmlPlugin` plugin before other bundles.

Comment: I just tried it. It works and adds the necessary JS File (just had to exlcude SourceMaps).
But honestly, in my books something as importing a Js File should not be this hard (I spent multiple hours trying different approaches).
And while this approach works, I think it's far from ideal.

Anyway, thanks. But webpack now complains `Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined` on line 1 of the imported file.

Comment: So probably need to transpile this ES6 module in something the browser understands... oh myyy...

Comment: @Arikael, what exactly is hard? You're are using a build tool and you should use the approach it supports. You need a new entry point because ESM modules are static and are executed before the module that imports them is executed. The last error can probably be a separate question. If Webpack is configured correctly it will transpile `module` into its own require format

Answer (score 0):

import external javascript files in your index.html file's head section which is the entrypoint to your application, using normal html script tag
example:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=false"></script>
```

Comment: but this would lead to an additional request.

Comment: yes..  but it will load the external javascript files only once when the index.html page (i.e your single page application) is loaded to the browser @Arikael

Comment: isn't there a way to include it directly into the app (import/require etc.?)

Comment: you may add the same script tag in your application's html template where you are going to use it. @Arikael. You cannot import javascript files in .ts files as .ts is the typescript file and .js is javascript. So you will either have to import all external .js files in your html templates or index.html file